# Integral. $\int_{0}^{s}{\lambda \cdot |t|^{q-2}\cdot t\text{dt}}$

Tags: analysis

How can I calculate the following integral :

> $$\int_{0}^{s}{\lambda \cdot |t|^{q-2}\cdot t\text{dt}}$$

$q \geq6$, $\lambda >0$ and $ s \in \mathbb{R}$.

It's hard for me to calcualte this integral because I don't know what I have to do with the module.

Thanks :)

Comment: you dont have to do anything with the module since you are integrating from 0 to 8. Just open it positively.

Comment: @mathemagician why from $0$ to $8$. The heads of the integral are $0$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $s \in \mathbb{R}$ or should $s$ be $\geqslant0$?  Otherwise the integral doesn't quite make sense.  If $s \geqslant0$, then you can remove then absolute value.

Comment: Nevertheless: if $s\geqslant0$ you are integrating $t\mapsto\lambda t^{q-1}$ from $0$ to $s$, if $s\leqslant0$ you are integrating $t\mapsto-\lambda(-t)^{q-1}$ from $0$ to $s$.

Comment: @thang you are wrong. $s$ can be >0 or also <0.

Comment: then just break it into two cases.  s can only be either $\geqslant 0$ or $< 0$, but not both.  in each of these case, you can deal with the absolute value appropriately.

Comment: can you give a complete proof, please ?

Comment: Why don't you *at least try* to do it yourself?

Comment: i tried. but i don't know, it seems it is impossible for me

Comment: @Iuli - Sorry. Apparently I need glasses. In any case, if $s=0$ the integral is obv. 0. If $s>0$ open the absolute val positively and if $s<0$ use the fact that $\int_a^b f dx=-\int_b^a f dx$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to discuss this problem by distinguishing two cases:

- $s>0$: then $0<t<s$ so that $t$ is always positive. For $t>0$, we have $|t|=t$ and thus 
  $$\int_{0}^{s}\lambda  |t|^{q-2} t \,dt = \int_{0}^{s}\lambda  t^{q-2} t \,dt =
   \lambda \int_{0}^{s}  t^{q-1} \,dt = \frac{\lambda s^{q}}{q}.$$
- $s<0$: then $s<t<0$ so that $t$ is always negative. For $t<0$, we have $|t|=-t$
  and thus
  $$\int_{0}^{s}\lambda  |t|^{q-2} t \,dt = \int_{0}^{s}\lambda  (-t)^{q-2} t \,dt =
   \lambda \underbrace{(-1)^{q-2}}_{=(-1)^q}\int_{0}^{s}  t^{q-1} \,dt = (-1)^q\frac{\lambda  s^{q}}{q}.$$

You can write these two cases in a single formula
$$\int_{0}^{s}\lambda  |t|^{q-2} t \,dt = \frac{\lambda  |s|^{q}}{q}$$